# Convert a sync js function with blocking for loop for websocket updates to html table to async - JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop, asynchronous

I have a sync function which is blocking the DOM causing updates to slow down in javascript. Is it possible to convert it to an async function?

```
function setBids(gapPrice)
{
var startBuyPrice = this.bid
gapPrice=parseFloat(gapPrice)
var showMaximum = 15
var startBuyViewPrice = Math.floor(startBuyPrice/gapPrice)*gapPrice
var tmpOrder = {price:null,size:null,total: null}
var currentBuyViewPrice = startBuyViewPrice
var totalBuy=0;
var buys="";
var cntShow = 0
for(var price = startBuyPrice;cntShow<showMaximum;price -= 0.5)
{
   if(this.orderBook[price]==undefined)
      continue
   var tmpSize = this.orderBook[price].size;
   if(currentBuyViewPrice>price)
   {
      currentBuyViewPrice -= gapPrice
      tmpOrder['size'] = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(tmpOrder['size'])
      tmpOrder['total'] = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(totalBuy)
      tmpOrder['price'] = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(tmpOrder['price'].toFixed(1))
      if(tmpOrder['price'].indexOf('.')==-1)
         tmpOrder['price'] += '.0'
      buys+='<tr><td style="color:white !important;">'+tmpOrder['total']+'</td><td style="color:white !important;">'+tmpOrder['size']+'</td><td>'+tmpOrder['price']+'</td></tr>'
      tmpOrder = {price:null,size:null,total: null}
      cntShow += 1
   }
   totalBuy+=tmpSize;
   if(tmpOrder['price']==null)
   {
      tmpOrder['price'] = currentBuyViewPrice
      tmpOrder['size'] = tmpSize
   }
   else
   {
      tmpOrder['size'] += tmpSize   
   }   
}
$(".orderbook-table-bids tbody").html(buys)   
}
```

When websockets update come, this function is called frequently, setting showMaximum to 1 does not have an issue because the loop does not block, anything above 1 causes the page to hang. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with being called frequently or being synchronous. You've got a loop in there with no clear exit condition, and I'd bet you have infinite looping depending on the input (and on `showMaximum`).

Comment: The logic for this code is really all over the place.  You should be iterating on orderBook, and just have a `break` conditoin when 15 is reached.

Comment: I can't iterate orderbook. Orderbook has 30k objects in it. I have to find the top 12 based on the current price. If current price is 8000, I need 8001,8002 and so on along with the size to be grouped together. So the goal here is to create an orderbook grouping.

Comment: if I Set showMaximum=1 the page works fine.. Anything greater than that, it blocks other elements of the page.

Comment: You should still be iterating on orderBook.  It would be no different than now, but without having a broken exit condition as Bergi pointed out, which is why "showMaximum" is causing that problem.  It only works most likely because for some reason within that 30k you have only one match.  EDIT: if that is actually the problem.  You should step through the debugger and check what is actually happening.  It is unlikely that the browser lockup is just because of being called too often.

Comment: Okay, but iterating 30k records when the websocket is sending messages 20 times in a second might be very memory intensive. I'll give it a go and see if that works.

Comment: Before you do that, put a breakpoint in the debugger and step through to see if it ever reaches the end of that loop, and do a timing to make sure.  What I've said is only "the most likely" reason.  And irregardless of anything, you need an exit condition for `price`.  Possible price < 0 should be an exit condition.  Note that this means that you are actually iterating on _more_ than the 30K, including undefined values, and your loop's exit condition and logic is not benefiting from exiting early, and most likely the logic has problems.

Comment: The steps work fine as expected, the exit condition for price is not there, because I need data grouped by price. 
for example: if gapPrice is 5 and my orderbook is 8000, 8001, 8002, 8003 and so on, I need data grouped by 8000, 8005, 8010 and so on until showMaximum number of row is reached.  
The exit condition is showMaximum which determines the number of groups I want. I tried map reduce but this seems to be the best result there. I was just hoping if this can be done in an async way.